# Python3 and pip3 on unix

Tags: python, unix

I'm trying to install 3.4 python and pip3 on unix. However it seems like pip3 is installed on 3.2.

When i run Python3 --version it returns

```
Python 3.4.1
```

However when i run pip3 --version

```
pip 6.0.8 from /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip-6.0.8-py3.2.egg (python 3.2)
```

I'm then trying to point pip3 on python 3.4 by editing this:

```
 nano /usr/bin/pip3
```

and then insert

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4
```

So when i after this try to install requests it says that it allways is installed on 3.2. However i want to run on 3.4

```
pip3 install requests
```

returns

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests in /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages
```

How can i make it point to 3.4 instead of 3.2?

**OUTPUT**

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 feb 17 08:52 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 feb 17 08:52 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2993744 feb 27  2014 /usr/bin/python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    1652 feb 27  2014 /usr/bin/python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 feb 17 08:53 /usr/bin/python2-config -> python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 apr 10  2013 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      11 feb 27  2014 /usr/bin/python3.2 -> python3.2mu
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      18 feb 27  2014 /usr/bin/python3.2-config -> python3.2mu-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2954048 feb 27  2014 /usr/bin/python3.2mu
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    1820 feb 27  2014 /usr/bin/python3.2mu-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 apr 10  2013 /usr/bin/python3-config -> python3.2-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      11 apr 10  2013 /usr/bin/python3mu -> python3.2mu
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      18 apr 10  2013 /usr/bin/python3mu-config -> python3.2mu-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 feb 17 08:53 /usr/bin/python-config ->     python2.7-config
```

Comment: Changing the interpreter to `/usr/bin/python3.4` can't work; `pip` will still have its internal configuration pointing to `/usr/local/lib/python3.2`. What you need, is a different `pip3`. Maybe you have a `pip3.4` that does the trick? If so, you can rename it to `pip3`, or rename the original `pip3` to `pip3.2` and then create a symlink, or whatnot.

Comment: okay for the project i'm using 3.2 is fine aswell. Is there a way to set the default python3 to 3.2 so when i write python3 --version it will say python 3.2 instead of 3.4?

Comment: Same thing. You have somewhere probably an executable named `python3.4` and a symlink `python3` that points to `python3.4`. If you repoint it to `python3.2` then you'll force the 3.2 version to be executed when you type `python3`.

Comment: Okay i'm new to python and unix, i just need it in order to use an API. Could u create a answer on how to repoint such?

Comment: Ummm sorry Peter, I have no idea what your system looks like, a generic answer can't be given. I can help you out tho. What is the output when you do: `ls -l /usr/bin/python*`? I might see what Pythonesque stuff you have there.

Comment: i've added to question the output

Comment: This is exactly why `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` should be required dev tools! :)

Comment: @AdamSmith do you suggest i install these or what :) ?

Comment: @PeterPik virtual environments allow you to completely compartmentalize your python installations. This is useful before you begin working on a project, but if you've already written code then that ship has sailed.